# Fluentbit to GCS

Tags: fluent-bit, google-cloud-storage

I was wondering if Fluentbit had a Google Cloud Storage (GCS) output plugin? I found this [fluent-bit-go-gcs repo](https://github.com/arktos-venture/fluent-bit-go-gcs) on github but not sure if this is still something that's being maintained.

Any examples of Fluentbit configs that output to GCS/other tips on this will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: See if this help 
https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/issues/4165#issuecomment-936776478
https://github.com/aws/aws-for-fluent-bit/issues/254